# Locally installed executable dependencies fail using npm run/yarn run on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a Windows machine as my primary development machine. I usually use WSL for most of my projects, but one of my electron projects requires me to work in the Windows environment. So I've set up node, npm, yarn & git on the Windows side as well. But I am having troubles with locally installed dependencies. 
Say, I have added concurrently to my project using `yarn add concurrently`. Now if I do `yarn run concurrently`, it fails saying that `'C:\Users\Praneet\Projects\my-project\node_modules\.bin\concurrently' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. But if I do `yarn run concurrently.cmd`, it works. Same thing happens for scripts in package.json. I have to change `react-scripts start` to `react-scripts.cmd start` to make it work. But I don't want to do this for every script, because there are other devs working with me who use MacOS. I will be really grateful if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running these commands using Windows Powershell? It might work.

Another option (the one I use when I must code in a Windows environment) is to use Git Bash: https://gitforwindows.org/

It simulates a BASH for Windows, so the commands you are trying to run should work without the `.cmd`.

Comment: I don't want to use PowerShell tbh. I'll try the Git Bash approach and let you know. Thanks for the help